# Microsoft word VBA macro search only certain table

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a way in VBA to search and delete cells that are only in a certain table, maybe based on the table title?

I have code written to delete cells that match the word I am looking for but this searches all tables in the document.

```
Dim myString As String

    myString = "5"
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = myString
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWholeWord = True
    End With
    Do While Selection.Find.Execute
        If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            Selection.Rows.Delete
        End If
```

What would be the best way to limit this to only 1 table?

Also this would delete any cell that contains the word I am looking for, is there a way to limit it to cells that only contain what I am searching for.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: One way would be to bookmark the table so that you can search only in the bookmarked range.  For the found text you can check if Len (.Text) = len(.cells(1).range.text) (NB after adjusting for the invisible characters in each cell)

Comment: You could do a nested search -  first find the table with the required text, then find the string within that table then test which cell the string is in.